# UIViewController multiple UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

This is just to confirm my solution:
I have two UIView that I would like to swap between controlled by the UIViewController

In IB I have created 3 UIViews:
TopView
A_View
B_View

Then in ViewDidLoad I add [

```
[self addSubView] A_View];
```

Then in some IBAction method I do this

[A_View removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:B_View];

This is indeed swapping the two views, with TopView just sitting there. But my first thought was just to call `[[self view] removeFromSuperView]];` and then add B_view.
This gives me an empty screen?

So is my solution the right way?

Thanks in advance
Regards
Christian

Comment: Please take time formatting your question. At this time I don't know what is it that you really asking us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That way is fine and perfectly straightforward.

If you're on iOS 4.0 or later, you can also use the `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` method in UIView, which removes and adds for you, plus provides a transition animation.

The reason `[[self view] removeFromSuperview]` left you with a blank window is because you're removing your controller's *base* view object (including it's subviews, e.g. Top_View, etc) from *it's* superview (likely the window object).  Your solution works when you remove A_View and add B_View, as both are being added or removed as subviews to your controller's view, i.e. `self.view`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me. It's a pretty normal swapping style, just remove one and add the other.

You should always watch out with modifying the UIViewController's view itself. Your solution is fine.